# Haskell - Export data constructor

Tags: haskell

I have this data on my Module Formula :

```
data Formula = Formula {
    typeFormula :: String, 
    nbClauses   :: Int,
    nbVars      :: Int,
    clauses     :: Clauses       
}
```

And I want to export it but I don't know the right syntax :

```
module Formula (
    Formula ( Formula ),
    solve
) where
```

Someone can tell me the right syntax please ?

Comment: But this doesnt work x)

Comment: Then post a error message, at least.

Comment: Console.hs:11:29:
    `typeFormula' is not a (visible) field of constructor `Formula'

Comment: In your export list `Formula (Formula)` means you've only exported the type `Formula` and its constructor `Formula` but not the projections `typeFormula`, `nbClauses`, etc. If you want to export these too, you can write `Formula(..)` instead.

Answer (score 25):

Some of your confusion is coming from having the same module name as the constructor you're trying to export.

```
module Formula (
    Formula ( Formula ),
    solve
) where
```

Should be

```
module Formula (
    Formula (..),
    solve
) where
```

Or

```
module Formula (
    module Formula ( Formula (..)),
    solve
) where
```

---

Your current export statement says, in the Module Formula, export the Type `Formula` defined in the Module Formula and the function solve (that is in scope for the module, wherever it is defined))

The `(..)` syntax means, export all constructors for the preceding type. In your case, it is equivalent to the explicit

```
module Formula (
    Formula (typeFormula,nbClauses, nbVars,clauses),
    solve
) where
```

Comment: I'm not sure your third example is valid: it doesn't appear in [the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html)'s "5.2 Export Lists" subsection, and [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/OblongTomatoEquation) goes into infinite loop trying to compile it (it uses GHC 8.6.5).

Comment: Hmmm @WillNess I think it was allowed in an older version of GHC when this answer was written, but not in newer versions (it's just a compiler parse error for me now). However you can still write `module Formula (module Formula, ... )` to export the entire module.

Comment: right; but not what's shown in the answer at the moment.