# As pattern matching on data constructor from different module

Tags: haskell, types, module, pattern-matching

I have two modules,

`Lib.hs`

```
module Lib (Hi) where

data Hi = Hi Int Int
```

`Check.hs`

```
module Check (applyCheck) where
import Lib

applyCheck :: Hi -> (Hi, Hi)
applyCheck hi@(Hi a b) = (Hi a + b a - b, hi)
```

And the compiler gives the following error,

```
error:
Not in scope: data constructor ‘Hi’
Perhaps you meant variable ‘hi’
on line applyCheck hi@(Hi a b) = (Hi a + b a - b, hi)
```

This does not happen when I declare `Hi` in `Check.hs`. What am I doing wrong here? Is there a different way to pattern match a data constructor in a different module?

Comment: Near duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929556/haskell-export-data-constructor. You are currently only exporting the *type* constructor, not the data constructor, by using `module Lib (Hi)`.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find the question with the words I was searching for. Do I delete the question or close it?

Comment: If you think your question is adequately answered, you can close this as a duplicate.